# 3d cube using canvas. Need a little improvement

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I made this 3d cube using the following code

```
Matrix mMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();

canvas.save();
camera.save();
camera.rotateY(-angle);
camera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mMatrix.preTranslate(-width, 0);
mMatrix.postTranslate(width, 0);
canvas.concat(mMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
camera.restore();
canvas.restore();

camera.rotateY(90 - angle);
camera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mMatrix.preTranslate(-width, 0);
mMatrix.postTranslate(width2, 0);
canvas.concat(mMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, width, 0, null);
```

This is what it gives

[image]

But what I need is

[image]

It's because when Camera rotates the images, some part of the image gets hidden.
Like this[image]

But I think this can be done.

Comment: can u please share the code for creating cube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty easy actually. The image had to be translated by half it's width/height along the axis it was being rotated.

So the following changes did it

```
mMatrix.preTranslate(-width, -height / 2);
mMatrix.postTranslate(width, height / 2);
```

Comment: @Vivekanand The code is in the question. Use it after making the changes in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so informal, its because of the desperate situation. I dont really want the complete code some tutorial of to how the implementation is done would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri, can u please share the code for creating 3d cube